JSON path expression to parse data into a table
i have some data i'm trying to load into a table and im having trouble figuring out the correct path expression to parse it.
sample data:
{"data": {
"2": {
  "high": 190,
  "highTime": 1716591041,
  "low": 195,
  "lowTime": 1716591190},
"6": {
  "high": 212800,
  "highTime": 1716589695,
  "low": 188000,
  "lowTime": 1716591178},
"8": {
  "high": 196409,
  "highTime": 1716589718,
  "low": 188835,
  "lowTime": 1716591175}}}

i would love to be able to parse this out to look something like this:

i can get the high, highTime, low, and lowTime no problem with an expression of $.data.* but organizing them along with their respective Id #'s is proving to be tricky.  any help would be appreciated.

What do you mean by "parse it out"? Do you mean you want to produce an actual image with the data in boxes as shown?

@jhnc no i meant just to produce a table of data that looks like the image i provided.
